# Building V8 with GYP

Tags: v8, gyp

I've been able to get V8 to compile when it uses GN, but for older versions that use GYP, I get this error upon running `make native` for V8 version 4.8.47:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'third_party/icu/icu.gypi' needed by 'out/Makefile.native'. Stop.
```

What is necessary to make it compile?

Answer (score 0):

(V8 developer here.)

The official answer is that V8 4.8 is way outdated (six years!) and you shouldn't use it. Old JS engines are dangerous. 4.8.47 is a particularly bad choice as it wasn't even a branch head that would have received security/stability fixes for a while; it's just a random snapshot that could be arbitrarily broken.

That said, if memory serves, before we had `gclient sync` (which I guess you've tried?) we had `make dependencies`, so you can try that. If it's broken (e.g., it may well be that it tries to download stuff from URLs/repositories that are no longer available), you're on your own (e.g., you may have to find mirrors that still work).

Comment: My reason for using version 4.8.47 is that it is the last version of V8 that defines builtin functions and objects using JavaScript, which is something I want to experiment with.

Comment: `make dependencies` resulted in a message saying to use `gclient sync` instead, which in turn complained about bo configuration file being present. I downloaded the GitHub archive of the `4.8.47` branch. Is that not enough to work with?

Comment: Downloading the GitHub archive has never been enough. See [v8.dev/docs/source-code](https://v8.dev/docs/source-code).

Comment: I am aware of that. That's what I did for building the latest version. On getting those errors for the `4.8.47` branch, I copied my first V8's `gclient` configuration file into the root directory of `4.8.47` and ran `gclient sync -v -j2`.

Comment: Why would whatever repositories no longer be available when all the code and dependencies are hosted on Google's servers?